# What do I have to do in order to be able to receive notifications?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In the event of a database error in an application, what do I have do in order to be able to receive notifications?

Should I create an alert in SQL Server and use the `RAISERROR` command within the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that's a pretty way to go about it.  You can create a new user-defined error message using [`sys.sp_addmessage`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178649.aspx), which will in turn store it in `sys.messages`.  And then when you add your alert, you can specify to alert on a specific `@message_id`.  This can be seen through the definition of [`sp_add_alert`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189531.aspx).

Then when you have this alert in place and the error message is raised, you should get a notification provided that side is all set up correctly.